# What is the difficulty in talking about Fourier Series of non-Lebesgue integrable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I  have a question about Fourier Series. 
In some books the author says : "It is difficult to talk about Fourier Series of non - Lebesgue integrable function"
What does it mean really? What can we say about Fourier series of $f\notin L^1[-\pi,\pi]$??

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you need to bring in that case the concept of generalized functions or distributions.

Comment: Defining Fourier coefficients of a function requires a notion of integration or an appropriate linear functional on some space of concern which coincides with Fourier coefficients in some suitable subspace. So your question must be: Is there any collection of generalized functionals which coincides with Fourier coefficients? It it unique?
But even to define such a functional is quite difficult without integrability assumption.

Comment: @HyJu what you mean "quite difficult"? What is difficulty?

Comment: I also don't get what the author means. The Fourier series doesn't have to exist for even Lebesgue integrale functions. You'd need something like $\hat{f} \in \mathscr{l^1}(\mathbb{Z})$ or other properties hat imply this.

Comment: Difficulty is a subjective notion. He probably means that there it is not difficult to define the Fourier series of a Lebesgue integrable function because the Fourier coefficients are obviously well defined, while for other functions/distributions, one needs extra arguments.

Comment: We know the Fourier coefficients $c_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-i\pi n x}dx$ are well-defined when $f \in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$. We can extend it to the case $f$ being the $k$th derivative of a function $g \in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$, and by closure when $f$ is approximated (as a distribution) by such finite order distributions. Otherwise, it becomes really complicated to make sense to the Fourier series, and we prefer not to mention it.

Comment: @MarvinF. You do not need $\hat{f}\in\ell^1$.

Comment: @AD. Okay, you are right, not necessarily. I thought of $| \sum \hat{f}(k) z^k| \leq ||f||_{\mathscr{l}^1}$ but of course the inequality could be strict. The other conditions for existence of the Fourier series that came to my mind, for example $|\hat{f}(k)| \leq \frac{1}{n^2} ||f''||_{L^1}$ or the Bernsteins theorem $\sum |\hat{f}(k)| \leq c ||f||_{\alpha}$ (Norm on the Holder space) imply in the end $f \in \mathscr{l}^1$. Could you tell me what other conditions there are for which we can guarentee the existence of the Fourier series but $\hat f$ is not in $\mathscr{l}^1$?

Comment: @MarvinF. The term Fourier series has nothing to do with the convergence of the series, it can be view upon as a formal relation $f\mapsto c_0$ (that is, the space of sequences that tend to 0 at infinity). If we demand convergence, we could not look at all of $L^1$, actually Kolmogorov showed us that the series can diverge everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the reference from where you quote that acclamation.

What you meant to say was

> If $\forall p\in (0,\infty], \ f\notin L^p([-\pi, \pi))$, then what can we say about Fourier series of $f$??

For a general definition of measurability of a function and $L^p$ spaces, please see  [Definition of the periodic $L^p$ space on torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164685/definition-of-the-periodic-lp-space-on-torus/3026118#3026118) . Note the difference between *measurability* and *integrability* of a function.

Given a measure $\mu_x$, any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and an *arbitrary* function $f$, $f$ must verify integrability conditions in order to calculate $$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{inx}d\mu_x .$$
If $f$ is measurable with respect to Lebesgue measure, it is widely studied how to check whether this integral converges depending on the properties of $f$, and thus if this function, for some $p$, belongs to any $L^p([-\pi, \pi))$ space.

In the other hand, the convergence of that integral ---for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$--- is not so well studied for $f$ not Lebesgue-measurable.